# Redux -- where should the heavy lifting happen -- reducer, action, container, or presentation component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been trying to implement the container/presentational component paradigm that is taught [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.3smkmquu3). I'm getting a little confused, however, on where some of my code should go.

Let's say I have a simple list of items. When one item is clicked on, it should be removed from the list. Should the code to modify the list go in my reducer, action creator, container component, or presentational component?

Reducer:

```
case 'REMOVE_ITEM':
  return Object.assign({}, state, {items: action.value})
```

Action creator:

```
export function removeItem(items) {
  return {
    type: 'REMOVE_ITEM',
    value: items
  };
}
```

And now our container component:

```
import ItemsList from './ItemsList';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions';

var mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    items: state.itemsList.items
  };
};

var mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
    onItemClicked: function(items) {
      dispatch(actions.removeItem(items));
    }
  };
};

var ItemsListContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ItemsList);

module.exports = ItemsListContainer;
```

And finally the presentational component:

```
import React from 'react';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  showRows: function() {
    return this.props.items.map(item => {
      return (
        <li key={item.id} onClick={this.props.onItemClicked}>{item.title}</li>
      );
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.showRows()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Then, at some point, we'll need some code to remove the list item. When the item is clicked on, we'll need to splice it from the list of items.
Where should that code go?

I could see it going in the presentational component and then calling the onItemClicked callback from the container component after it has modified the list.

I could see it going in the container component so the presentational component is as dumb as can be. I'd need a way to access the state, though (to get the items), and since I'm already passing the items as props into the presentational component, it would make more sense to me to do it there.

I could see it going in the action creator, with the removed item as the second parameter to the removeItem function.

It seems like a bad idea to put it in the reducer, since doing a bunch of calculations (modifying the array) seems like the thing that should happen before the action is dispatched, not after.

Where should the heavy lifting of modifying the array happen? It seems it should go in the presentational component, but I know those are supposed to be dumb components...

Comment: i'll take reducer for 500 alex. reducers are where you change state.

Comment: It should go in your reducer. Reducers are responsible for responding to actions and returning a new state, so in this case, you would return a new state with the item removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about it this way:

DumbComponent (View/Accepts Input) -> SmartComponent (RespondsToInput by firing a dispatch) -> ActionCreator (Creates the necessary action, gives a payload if necessary - in this case, the index you need to filter out) -> Reducer (Responds to the action by modifying and returning a new state.)

In your reducer you'll do something like:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { items: state.items.filter((item, index) => index !== payload) });
```

So do the calculations/heavy lifting in the reducer, if it modifies state, the code should be where the state is modified.

Comment: So the component's job is just to dispatch an action, the action just notifies the reducer (with the payload), and the reducer's job is to do the heavy lifting?

Comment: yep. Think of ui = fn(state). The UI part should be all the react stuff - and should be taking props in from the redux store. Redux is responsible for taking a state object, doing something with it, and returning a new state object to be passed down as props in React. The communication between the two happens with the dispatch and the action, where a component or a thunked action (for async info) may send necessary info other than the type  to the reducer in the form of a payload (index, userId etc, think of this almost as fn params) that the reducer can then use to modify state.

Comment: @GeoffreyAbdallah: Why can't action do the heavy lifting? So that all the logic stays there and store just modifies whatever it's been provided. And any action ( apart from this ) can also modify the state

Comment: @AbhinavSingi Theoretically you could, and nothing is stopping you from doing so. That said, I think regarding separation of concerns it makes more sense for the heavy lifting to be handled in the store. This is two fold - I view actions as specifically being messages between the view and the store, whether they be sync or async (so they should be light weight), and because any further lifting outside of the server (for async payloads) should be done in the store to easily discern why and how the state got from A to B (which is harder to do if there is computation done in all three places).